# jQuery loop is only returning the last element of an array

Tags: jquery, loops, closures

I'm only receiving the last element of the array that I'm looping through that is within a function.

I've tried a basic for loop and a forEach loop and nothing is working.

```
(function(d,$){
  let titles = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bop"]
  $('li').forEach((ele, i)=>{
    $("li").attr('titles', `i am ${titles[i]}`)
  })
})(dojo, dojo.query);
```

Each `li` in the DOM should have a unique title, the first one should be foo, second one bar and so on.

Currently all the `li`'s have a title of bop.

Comment: `$('li').attr()` affects _all_ the elements for _every_ iteration. Use `$(this).attr()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just change you forEach loop,

```
$('li').each((i, elm)=>{
  $(this).attr('titles', `i am ${titles[i]}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
    (function(d,$){
  let titles = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bop"]
  titles.forEach((ele, i)=>{
    $(`li.${titles[i]}`).attr('titles', `i am ${titles[i]}`)
  })
})(dojo, dojo.query);
```

The issue was that I was setting each li every time it looped. So instead I just loop through the array I created and set the target and the message with the interpolation.